# Entity Framework SaveChanges not using provided Schema

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-6

Assume a (simplified) domain object like this:

```
public class MyObject
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public String Field1 { get; set; }
    public String Field2 { get; set; }
}
```

Attached to my context in this manner:

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<MyObject> MyObjects { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("myschema");

        modelBuilder.Configurations
            .AddFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

        modelBuilder.Conventions
            .AddFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
    }
}
```

And mapped like so:

```
public class MyObjectMapping : EntityTypeConfiguration<MyObject>
{
    public MyObjectMapping()
    {
        ToTable("MyObject", "myschema");
        HasKey(x => x.Id);
    }
}
```

Yet, if I load my object from xml and save it to DB:

```
var myObject = MyObjects.FromXml(xmlFilepath).ToDomain();
var context = new MyDbContext();
context.MyObjects.Add(myObject);
context.SaveChanges();
```

I get this error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException Invalid object name
>   'dbo.MyObjects'.

Where `dbo` should be `myschema` instead.

**Question**

> What should I do to make sure the correct schema is used instead of
>   dbo?

I set the schema specifically on the context and mapping definition, what am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks to be a bug in `EF6`, if I set things up the `DatAnnotation` way instead of `Fluent`, I can generate the database I want. So I decorate my domain object like so:

```
[Table("MyObject", Schema = "myschema")]
public class MyObject
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public String Field1 { get; set; }
    public String Field2 { get; set; }
}
```

That fixed it for me.